# C# object frequency in List<>, by object property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an object Loan that contains a property object called Book.

```
class Loan {
  Book book;
  string user;
}

public class Book
{

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int AuthId { get; set; }
    public int BookDetailsId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BookCopies { get; set; }

    public virtual Auhtor Auhtor { get; set; 
    public virtual BookDetail BookDetail { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I have a `List<Loan> allLoans` and I want to find **which book appears the most in that list** (which is the most frequent one?).

How could I do that?

Comment: How do you compare `Book`s, when are they equal?

Comment: Show us your effort and explain what defines an unique `Book`. Try to look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) and it's answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I added Book class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` or implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Book>` which you can use in many LINQ entension methods like `GroupBy` or (which i prefer) `ToLookup`:

```
public class BookComparer : IEqualityComparer<Book>
{
    public bool Equals(Book x, Book y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return true;
        return x.BookId == y.BookId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Book obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.BookId;
    }
}
```

---

```
var bookComparer = new BookComparer();
var bookLookup = loans.ToLookup(l => l.book, bookComparer);
var maxCount = bookLookup.Max(bg => bg.Count());
IEnumerable<Book> booksWhichAppearMostOften = bookLookup
    .Where(bg => bg.Count() == maxCount)
    .Select(bg => bg.Key)
    .Distinct(bookComparer);
```

As you can see i've also taken into account the fact that multiple books could have been  loaned the same number of times. You can now use a `foreach` to "consume" them or another method like `ToList` to *materialize* a collection from the query.

If you just want to see all `BookID`s you can use `String.Join`:

```
var allBookIDs = String.Join(", ", booksWhichAppearMostOften.Select(b => b.BookId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GroupBy to do this.

```
var mostWantedBook = list
  .GroupBy(x => x.book)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
  .First()
  .book;
```

Make sure you have a working Equals on the books. They should either be comparable by instance or override Equals.

Depending on the situation, this is not a good solution. When the objects are stored in a database, and there are potentially many of them, you should consider using a database query to find the most frequently used book.